# css transition hover with font awesome

Tags: css, css-transitions, font-awesome

Trying to add a left chevron on hover but the transition isn't working

```css
div.bx-wrapper:hover div.bx-controls-direction::before{
   content: "\f053";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
 }
 
 div.bx-wrapper div.bx-controls-direction::before{
 opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
 }
```

Don't know where i made mistakes

Comment: Please add a link to awesome font in your snippet so we can test your code

Comment: Why not just add animation class on hover using script?

Comment: @SumitSahay why use script when it can be done with plain CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set all the CSS(including transition) on the default state of the selector and then only set `opacity:1;` on the hover state:

```css
div.bx-wrapper div.bx-controls-direction::before{
    content: "\f053";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}
    div.bx-wrapper:hover div.bx-controls-direction::before{
        opacity:1;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="bx-wrapper">
  Hover Me
  <div class="bx-controls-direction">FontAwesome</div>
</div>
```